# How to get password_verify to work for me

Tags: php, hash, bcrypt

Using password_hash() I am able to hash the password and store it as a long string in the database.

However, when I try to use password_verify(), I am having trouble confirming the value entered matches the hashed value stored in the database so that I can log in.

```
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE uid='$uid'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$hash_pwd = $row['pwd'];

if (password_verify($pwd, $hash_pwd)) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE uid='$uid' AND pwd='$hash_pwd'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if (!$row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Your username or password is incorrect!";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
      }
 }
```

Comment: Why `SELECT * FROM User WHERE uid='$uid' AND pwd='$hash_pwd'`? The `if (password_verify($pwd, $hash_pwd)) {` already tells you it matched.. You also are open to SQL injections.

Comment: Make sure your `pwd` column in your database allows at least 255 characters. Maybe your column is not saving the entire hash (gets cut off when stored)?

Comment: @Rasclatt - thank you! That was so simple. That was the problem.

Comment: @chris85 - am I open to SQL Injections because I have no error check on my $uid POST?

Comment: No you are open to sql injection because you are putting your post values right into your sql statement. You should `bind_param`

Comment: You need to parameterize your query additionally your second query is unneeded. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.

Comment: You should learn resource management deeper, there are double queries on your logic with the same result, which is wasting resource.

Comment: @RendyEkoPrastiyo - I see what you are saying, but the first instance I am fetching 'pwd' so that I can de-hash it, then I fetch it again with the de-hashed value. I tried commenting out the second $sql and $result inside the if, but that did not work. Any suggestions, please?